# How to input formula in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to input a formula in a cell that calculates the division of a cell by a constant value that is contained in another sheet in the same workbook, and this is done in a FOR Loop, so that formula can be written in multiples cells.
So far I tried this method but it returns the error #NAME, how can I do it right?

`

```
`Sub ProcessarProjecaoEst()

Dim fLine, qtdMeses, LastLine, lineTitle, LastCol, LastColTitle, valor_col, valor_parc
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Leilao")
Set wparam = wb.Sheets("Parametros")

ws.Activate

qtdMeses = ws.Range("B4")
lineTitle = 11
PrimeiraColunaQtde = 13


' Ativa a aba PARAMETROS
wparam.Activate
qtdeLinhasParam = wparam.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Ativa a aba LEILAO
ws.Activate
qtdeLinhasLeilao = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For lineParam = 6 To qtdeLinhasParam

    qtdMeses = wparam.Range("C" & lineParam)
    Range("FW5").Value = qtdMeses
    For lineLeilao = 12 To qtdeLinhasLeilao
    
        If (ws.Range("A" & lineLeilao).Value = "0") And ws.Range("B" & lineLeilao).Value = "Lote " + wparam.Range("A" & lineParam) Then
     
            'Gerar Cabecalhos
            For i = 1 To qtdMeses
                
                    'Se for primeira PARCELA
                    If (i = 1) Then
                            LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            LastColTitle = PrimeiraColunaQtde
                            valueMes = wparam.Range("B" & lineParam).Value
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)) = valueMes
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Font.Color = Black
                            
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)) = "Parcela" & i
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                                                
                            LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)) = "Parcela" & i
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                            '11
                            LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            LastCol = PrimeiraColunaQtde
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)) = "Qtde"
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol)).Font.Bold = True
                            
                            LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)) = "Valor"
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).WrapText = True
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                            ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                        
                    Else
                           LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           valueMes = wparam.Range("B" & lineParam).Value
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]+31)"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = Black
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 3, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                           
                                      
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)) = "Parcela" & i
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                                              
                                                     
                           LastColTitle = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 2, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)) = "Parcela" & i
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(21, 48, 65)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 2, LastColTitle + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                    
                           '11
                           LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)) = "Qtde"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Color = Black
                           
                           LastCol = ws.Cells(lineLeilao - 1, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)) = "Valor"
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).WrapText = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Size = 9
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                           ws.Range(Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1), Cells(lineLeilao - 1, LastCol + 1)).Font.Color = Black
             
             End If
                
            Next
              

    LastCol = ws.Cells(11, 16384).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'Inserindo Fórmulas
    LastLine = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Row = 11 To LastLine
        For col = PrimeiraColunaQtde To LastCol
            valor_col = col - 1
            valor_parc = ws.Range(Cells(Row, valor_col), Cells(Row, valor_col)).Value
            If ws.Range("A" & Row).Value = "F1" Then
                 If ws.Range(Cells(lineTitle, col), Cells(lineTitle, col)).Value = "Qtde" Then
                     ' Qtde Dividida
                      ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).NumberFormat = "0"
                      ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)) = ws.Range(Cells(Row, 4), Cells(Row, 4)).Value / qtdMeses
                 Else
                    ' Valor dividido
                       ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).NumberFormat = _
                        "_-[$R$-pt-BR] * #,##0.00_-;-[$R$-pt-BR] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$R$-pt-BR] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
                     ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).Formula = "= ws.Range(Cells(Row, col-1),Cells(Row, col-1))/qtdMeses"
                     'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/Parametros!R[-8]C[-11]"
                     ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).ColumnWidth = 15
                    'If col = LastCol Then
                        'LastLine = ws.Cells(Row, "D").End(xlUp).Row
                        'Exit For
                    'End If
                 End If
                If ws.Range("A" & Row).Value = "" Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            
        Next
        
    Next

     End If
    Next
Next`
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try changing of `"= ws.Range(Cells(Row, col-1),Cells(Row, col-1))/qtdMeses"` with `"=" &  ws.Range(Cells(Row, col-1).address & "," & Cells(Row, col-1).address & ")/" & qtdMeses`. You can check it, to see its return, using `Debug.print "=" &  ws.Range(Cells(Row, col-1).address & "," & Cells(Row, col-1).address & ")/" & qtdMeses` and see what it looks in Immediate Window...

Comment: I didn't understand the construction you described, could you write the complete line of code how it should be, please?

Comment: Using your ideia @FaneDuru and using FormulaR1C1 i was able to reach the expected result. The final answer for my problem is:
`ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-1]/" & qtdMeses`

Comment: Glad you could solve it. But if you created the code is should be extremely easy to find the place where to be changed. Anyhow, in such cases you could use `Find` (`Ctrl + F`) and search for "= ws.Range(Cells(Row, col-1),Cells(Row, col-1))/qtdMeses". It has been taken from your code. Then, replace it with `"=" &  ws.Range(Cells(Row, col-1).address & "," & Cells(Row, col-1).address & ")/" & qtdMeses`...

Comment: @FaneDuru could you pass me some way to contact you? So you can help me in other questions? You seen to be expert in VBA and i would appreciate that

Comment: I am not an expert... When you place a new question, tagging me should be enough (here or in another place). If I will be available I will try helping. If not, somebody else will solve your problem, I think...

Comment: @FaneDuru can you help me with this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75933386/how-to-use-a-constant-variable-in-r1c1-formula-vba?noredirect=1#comment133931631_75933386