# How to use a constant variable in R1C1 Formula vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to input a formula in a cell that will use a constant storaged in a variable. However, when I try to run the mvba, it results in error 1004.
What is the correct method to input the variable in the formula?

At first, I tried the formula as it follows:

[image]

And the results of dolar was correct and it's show in the cell as seen in the print bellow.

[image]

After, the formula is inputed in the cell and calculates but it show error #NAME

[image]

So I tried the code bellow

```
 ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R" & cotacao & "C[-1],Cotações!R6C2:R25C3,2,0),""-"")" 
 dolar = ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).Value
 ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*RC17/RC5*" & dolar
```

And the result i was the error 1004, object definition:

[image]

Comment: Your error is here:  `ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col)).FormulaR1C1` should be `ws.Range(ws.Cells(Row, col), ws.Cells(Row, col)).FormulaR1C1`

Comment: I edited the way you said, nothing changed

Comment: what is the value of `cotacao` when it errors?

Comment: `ws.Range(Cells(Row, col), Cells(Row, col))` is only one cell so just use `ws.Cells(Row, col)`

Comment: @ScottCraner  cotacao value is 9. The vlookup is working, the variable dolar receives the correct value. The problem is that the formula  RC[-1] * RC17/RC5 * dolar is returning #NAME, because it is not putting the value of dolar in the formula

Comment: What's the value of `dolar` when it fails?

Comment: Does the first formula return correctly? I mean does it raise an error? If not, try `Debug.print "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R" & cotacao & "C[-1],Cotações!R6C2:R25C3,2,0),""-""):Stop"  in a line above that one. Does it correctly return in `Immediate Window` when code stops? If it looks being correct, place a break point of the second line involving a formula and move the cursor over `dolar` to see its value when the code stops. Does it show what you need (a numeric value)? If yes, try also `Debug.Print "=RC[-1]*RC17/RC5*" & dolar & ""`. At the first glance, what do you expect from the last `""` ?

Comment: @FaneDuru I edited the post with more details

Comment: `"=RC[-1]*RC17/RC5* dolar"` is wrong. It should be `"=RC[-1]*RC17/RC5*" & dolar`. Otherwise, it uses the string "dolar", not the variable...